# GEE_No valid training data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, invalid-data

I am trying to conduct supervised classification using RF, however I face problems with my training data. I have my data as a point `shp` file, however, whenever I use it, it gives me the error "no valid data found".

What is the problem?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b4794b919d19602cccbc4620ff48bf01

```
             ///////////////LANDSAT8 DATA/////////////
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}


// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var dates = [
 // ee.DateRange('2020-04-01', '2020-04-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-04-16', '2020-05-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-06-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-07-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-08-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-09-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-10-01'),
 //ee.DateRange('2020-10-01', '2020-10-16'),
  
]
//var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5',
            // 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
             
var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

// //EVI
var addEVI= function(image){
  var evi= image.expression(
              '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+10000)',{
              NIR:image.select('SR_B5'),
              RED:image.select('SR_B4'),
              BLUE:image.select('SR_B2'),
            }).float().rename('EVI')
  return image.addBands(evi)
}

var list = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .map(addEVI)
      .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.select(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
      //.mean()
      .median()
      .rename(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.rename(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
});



// print(list)
// Map.addLayer(ROI, {}, 'ROI', false)


///create a stacked layer///
var stacked = ee.ImageCollection(list).toBands().clip(ROI);
Map.addLayer(stacked, {bands: ["3_NDVI", "5_NDVI", "8_NDVI"]}, 'Stacked', false);


//print(stacked,'stacked')


                       // ////Prepare the training dataset//////
      ///**take only 3000 points of my sample data****////                 
 var random = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Vpoints_EG,
  points: 3000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})                      

// // Sample the image data at the random points
var training = stacked.reduceRegions({
  collection: random,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 30
});


          //////////////Train RF classifier//////////////

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
});


var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified')
Map.addLayer(classified,{},'classification', true)


// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a set of points as the bounding geometry to randomPoints.  That's not how randomPoints works (the way you've coded it, you're essentially trying to intersect a bunch of random numbers with your points; the probability of actual intersection is 0).

Instead, you should use randomColumn to select a subset of your points.

```
random = Vpoints_EG.randomColumn().sort('random').limit(3000)
```

That said, the way you debug something like this is adding everything to the map.  You would easily have seen that `random` contained no points if you'd try to display it.